# Has the user liked the post before or not using Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Currently when a user likes a post, that like record gets added to my Likes table with the userId and the postId.

Now, when a user is looking at a post, I want to determine if they liked the post before or not. I understand that to do so, I need to determine this in my get request when i am calling for the post information.

When i am calling for post information, I need to check the Likes table for a record of the userId of the current user AND the postId for the current post. If this exists then i need to return a parameter called isLiked and set it to true, if it does not exist then isLiked=false.

Here is my Post model:

```
id: {
  type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
  primaryKey: true,
  autoIncrement: true,
},
title: {
  type: Sequelize.STRING,

},
userId: {
  type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
},
likesCount:{
  type:Sequelize.INTEGER,
  defaultValue:0,
  validate: {
            min: 0,
        }
},
```

Here is my Likes Model:

```
id: {
allowNull: false,
autoIncrement: true,
primaryKey: true,
type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
 },
 PostId: {
type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
references: {
  model: "Post",
  key: "id",
},
 },
 userId: {
type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
references: {
  model: "User",
  key: "id",
},
 },
```

Here is my User Model:

```
id: {
  type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
  primaryKey: true,
  autoIncrement: true,
},
name: {
  type: Sequelize.STRING,
 },
```

Here are my associations:

```
User.hasMany(Post, { foreignKey: "userId" });
Post.belongsTo(User, { foreignKey: "userId" });

Post.hasMany(Likes, { foreignKey: "PostId", targetKey: "id" });
Likes.belongsTo(Post, { foreignKey: "PostId", targetKey: "id" });

User.hasMany(Likes, { foreignKey: "userId", targetKey: "id" });
Likes.belongsTo(User, { foreignKey: "userId", targetKey: "id" });
```

Update

I kept researching and found since i am using a JWT middleware to sign my user token, and i am currently checking to see if the current user has any records in the likes table, i tried the following but can someone tell me if this approach is correct?

```
 router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
    const posts = await Post.findAll({
   order: [["createdAt", "DESC"]],
   include: [
  { model: Post_Image, attributes: ["id", "images"] },
  { model: Likes, attributes: ["id", "PostId", "userId"] },
  ],
  });

 if (!posts) return res.status(404).send();

 const baseUrl = config.get("assetsBaseUrl");

 const plainPosts = posts.map((x) => x.get({ plain: true }));
 const resultPosts = [];
  for (const post of plainPosts) {

 let isLiked = false;
 let like = await Likes.findOne({
where: {
[Op.and]: [{ PostId: post.id) }, { userId: 
req.user.id }],

  },
 });

if (like) isLiked = true;

const { Post_Images, ...postAttributes } = post;
const IMAGES = Post_Images.map((postImage) => ({
  url: `${baseUrl}${postImage.images}_full.jpg`,
  thumbnailUrl: `${baseUrl}${postImage.images}_thumb.jpg`,
}));
resultPosts.push({ ...postAttributes, images: IMAGES, isLiked 
});
}

res.send( resultPosts );

 });
```

Comment: show the whole route and also how you send a request to get isLiked

Comment: Hi @Anatoly, i am trying to create a query within my get all posts requests that checks the likes table for a record of the userId and the postId ifthis record exists then i will return a parameter called is Liked and set it to true, if it doesnt exist isLiked=false. I tried implementing this within my for(const post of plainPosts){} loop. I updated my question with an example. thank you

Comment: I think you need to simplify that. There a lot of questions and confusion. Be direct of what you need and what you have done. Remove info that are not necessary to be better. I will try to edit your post for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to request `Like` once again, you got all post's likes at your hand:

```
for (const post of plainPosts) {
 // check if we have any like among posts' likes that is made by a certain user
 const isLiked = post.Likes.some(x => x.userId === req.user.id);
 const { Post_Images, ...postAttributes } = post;
 ...
```

Comment: thank you for getting back to me, for each post i need to check in the database if there is a record of this userId and postId.

Comment: i just tested your solution and it worked, Thank you alot @Anatoly, but i was wondering why is my solution not correct (it got the same results)?

Comment: It just has a unnecessary request `Likes.findOne`. By the way you could simplify conditions in `where` option like this: `where: { 
PostId: post.id, userId: req.user.id }` because you have AND condition and you have different fields in conditions

Comment: So because Likes.findOne is an unnecessary request it is better to use your solution const isLiked = post.Likes.some(x => x.userId === req.user.id); but if i still want to go with my solution, i can use it like this  let isLiked = false;
    let like = await Likes.findOne({
    where: {
    PostId: post.id,userId: req.user.id
     },
    });
  if (like) isLiked = true; ? without the [Op.and]

Comment: Yes, you can. You even can use `count` instead of `findOne` because you don't need the found record itself.

Comment: Yes that is true, i just need the isLiked parameter. So it is a bad idea to use the Likes.findOne request? i will just go with the solution you have provided but will keep all these points in mind. Thank you @Anatoly :)

Comment: There is no need to request a like that is already requested among other likes along with a requested post. You just need to determine whether a like from a certain user among them or not.

Comment: Last thing can you just explain to me what the .some() method does?

Comment: `some` simply checks whether or not any elements of a given array satisfying a certain condition. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify all the fields unless you want to override something, otherwise Sequelize can generate most of the columns for you.

```js
const User = sequelize.define(
  'user',
  {
    name: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
    },
  },
  { /* options */ }
);

const Post = sequelize.define(
  'post',
  {
    title: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
    },
  },
  { /* options */ }
);

// the join table so you can reference it, but doesn't need any columns including primary key (unless you want to a "super join")
const Likes = sequelize.define(
  'likes',
  {}, // no columns here
  { /* options */ }
);
```

Creating the associations between the models will create most of the foreignKey fields automatically. Use the `through` keyword on the `Likes` relationships to make it many-to-many.

```js
// Users can have many Posts
User.hasMany(Post);

// Posts belong to one User
Post.belongsTo(User);

// Users can like more than one Post through the `likes` join table
User.hasMany(Post, { as: 'likes', through: 'likes' });

// Posts can be liked by more than one User through the `likes` join table
Post.hasMany(User, { as: 'likes', through: 'likes' });
```

You don't need to store the number of likes because you can summarize it through the join table.

```js
// Get the 'likes' count for a Post, instead of saving it on the post
const posts = await Post.findAll({
  attributes: {
    include: [
      [sequelize.fn('COUNT', sequelize.col('likes.userId')), 'likesCount'],
    ],
  },
  include: [
    {
      model: User,
      as: 'likes',
      though: 'likes',
      attributes: [],
      required: false,
    },
  ],
});

// `posts` will be an array of Post instances that have a likesCount property
posts.forEach((post) => {
  console.log(`The post ${post.title} has ${post.likesCount} likes.`);
});
```

For an individual (or more than one) Post you can get the list of users who liked it via the post (or use the `Like` model and it's relationships).

```js
// Get the user 'likes' for a Post
const post = await Post.findByPk(postId, {
  include: [
    {
      model: User,
      as: 'likes',
      though: 'likes',
      required: false,
    },
  ],
});

post.likes.forEach((like) => {
  console.log(`The user ${like.name} has liked the post ${post.title}.`);
});
```

Comment: Hi @doublesharp, thank you for getting back to me. Why is the association between likes and users many-many i thought it is 1-many since a user can have many likes but a like belongs to only 1 user. Also, i am trying to create a isLiked parameter which can either be true or false that i can use in my frontend. I already have another get request which is working correctly that gets me the likes of each individual user. I am just trying to create a query when getting all the posts to see if the user has liked this post before or not. again thank you

Comment: I have also edited the question and added the associations i am currently using.